# CMD prompt using existing file explorer?

Tags: cmd, vb6, windows-explorer

I just learned a simple command in cmd prompt to open a specific folder using file explorer. 
http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_open_windows_explorer.html

```
 explorer.exe /e, C:\users
```

Is it possible, to check if I already have a file explorer open, I just change the path?

I will be coding in VB6.

Thank you

I tried.

```
Set sh= CreteObject("Shell.Application")
sh.navigate("c:\users",,"Explorer")
```

The error I get is "Compile error: Expected: ="

same error when I try this way

```
Set sh = CreateObject("shell.application")
For Each w In sh
    w.navigate("C:\Users",,Explorer)
Next
```

random try. but still no luck:

```
Shell.navigate("C:\Users", , "explorer")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Basic use [Shell.Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774063(v=vs.85).aspx) COM Object, enumerate its [`Windows` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773974(v=vs.85).aspx), find the window you want and then use its [`Navigate` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa752093(v=vs.85).aspx) to change the address.

```
Dim sh As Shell
Set sh = New Shell
If sh.Application.Windows.Count > 0 Then
   sh.Application.Windows.Item(0).Navigate "r:\"
End If
```

P.S. In the `Project` menu, go to `References`, enable `Microsoft Shell Controls And Automation`.

Comment: isn't navigate method for internet explorer? what about windows explorer/FIle explorer?

Comment: I tried Set sh = CreateObject("shell.application") .  then sh.navigate("C:\Users" ,, "Explorer") . but no luck . thanks for the help. I added in original post , with VB6 code with code I tried. .

Comment: would you mind helping me doing the same thing but in VB.net . I tried but it does not seem to work in .net I already import Shell32.dll ..

Comment: @BobNoobGuy, I haven't used vb.net. Post a new question with your attempted code.

Comment: your answer works great. next I want to bring the windows to foreground/top .   Maybe you know how to get focus / bring to front foreground after that navigate "r:\"  line in your code?  thanks

Comment: @BobNoobGuy, searching for [visual basic window foreground](https://www.google.com/#q=visual+basic+window+foreground+) I see examples using WinAPI function `SetForegroundWindow`.